# Multiple android-support-v4 versions in same project

Tags: java, android, jar, android-support-library

I am using android-support-v4-r19 (last version) in my project and I need to use another library (jar) but this library uses android-support-v4 (older version) as well, so when I try to run my app I got this error:

```
Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoVersionImpl;

Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoVersionImpl;
```

I suppose it is because there are two different versions of android-support-v4 library, but I cannot remove android-support-v4 (older version) from this library because I have the jar file and I cannot remove android-support-v4-r19 from my project because there are classes that I need and do not exist in android-support-v4 (older version).

What can I do?

Comment: Are you saying that the `android-support-v4` code is actually embedded in the older jar? If so, it sounds like that's a bug.

Comment: Please check again, android-support library cannot be packed in a jar.

Comment: i have support libraries packed in jar. You cannot use two at once.

Comment: Support jars are locations in your android sdk folder at location      ` \extras\android\support\ `

Comment: what is the name of this "other library comprising on v4 " ?

Comment: @chrylis exactly, this library includes an older version of android-support-v4.

Comment: @RahulGupta this other library is already compiled (it is a jar file) and it includes an older version of android-support-v4 that causes the whole fuss

Comment: What is the name of that library ? is it a third party ? name ?

Answer (score 0):

Configure your build path. Remove the v4 library. IF you are not able to delete it from there, go to your project location and delete it from there. You cannot use two support libraries

Why are you not able to remove the v4 library ? is it in the Android Private Libraries folder. If it is remove the whole Private library folder.

or simpler way i have told you - Navigate to your project location and delete the v4 library (You can find the location of v4 library in the build path of your project . Locate your v4 library. The location also should be present there

Answer (score 0):

> I cannot remove android-support-v4 (older version) from this library because I have the jar file

I am interpreting this as meaning that the JAR file from "another library" includes classes from `android-support-v4`. In that case, you probably want to reconsider using "another library". Personally, I would not touch it with a three-meter pole.

However, you can try to recover from this by opening up the JAR file as a ZIP archive and getting rid of any `android.*` classes that you see. Then, the JAR will wind up using the classes from your project's own copy of `android-support-v4.jar`.

It is possible that this change will break "another library":

- Their versions of the `android.*` classes were modified, and the "another library developer did not refactor them into some other package, or
- General code changes in the Android Support package simply break "another library", in which case you either fix them with the source code of "another library", or you are in trouble

Comment: Yes, the library is a JAR file and it includes an older version of android-support-v4.

I opened the JAR and removed android.* references. I could compile it but it crashes when I run the app.

I've got a NoClassDefFoundError associated with a class that it's already defined in "another library"

Comment: @Danielle: Then you are going to have to go to the author of "another library" and get them to fix their JAR, to be able to use a more current version of the `android-support-v4.jar` (ideally by *not* baking in those classes).

Comment: I think it is the only solution that I have